# Как подписаться на изменения стора redux используя react hooks

Tags: reactjs, redux

```
export const HomeHeader = () => {

const filters = useSelector(state => state.filterReducer.category)
const loading = useSelector(state => state.filterReducer.loading)

const [filterArr, setFilter] = useState(filters)


const dispatch = useDispatch()

useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(loadingFilter())
  setFilter(filters)
}, [ filters, loading])



const {container,createPostWrapper, createIcon,
    createIconWrapper,filterWrapper} = styles


const handleFilter = (title) =>{
    dispatch(toggleFilter(title))
    console.log(filters)
}



if(loading){
    return <View><Text>Loading...</Text></View>
  } 

return (
    <View style={container}>
        <View style={createPostWrapper}>
            <CircleAvatar colorOfAvatar='#0067ff'>31</CircleAvatar>
            <TouchableOpacity style={createIconWrapper} >
                <Image style={createIcon} source={require('../../assets/create.png')}/>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        <View style={filterWrapper}>
            {
                filterArr.map((item, index)  => 
                    <Filter 
                        key={index} 
                        selected={item.status} 
                        handleFilter={handleFilter} 
                        >
                            {item.title}
                    </Filter>
                )
            }
        </View>
    </View>
)
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `useSelector` из библиотеки `react-redux`

Comment: Возможно у Вас есть пример применения? Так автору Вопроса и  остальным участникам сообщества будет проще применить Ваш совет без дополнительного гугления.